# CodeIgniter task scheduler taking the function to the task scheduler

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am new with CRON jobs, so I'm practicing it; for starters I am making a CRON job adding a user with CodeIgniter and PHP,
Here is my Model:

```
    <?php 
    class Cron_Model extends CI_Model{

    public function adduser($firstname,$lastname){
    $data = array(
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname
        );
    $query = $this->db->insert('user_account',$data);
    return $query;
       }

    }
```

AND : Here is my Controller:

```
    <?php
    class Cron_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->model('Cron_Model');

    // this controller can only be called from the command line
    if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) show_error('Direct access is not allowed');

}

public function AddAUser(){
    $fname = "JUNCEL";
    $lname = "CARREON";

    $this->Cron_Model->adduser($fname,$lname);
}

}

  ?>
```

I am going to add this to the database, even though the firstname and lastname is same it's okay this is only a trial work.

So now I am trying to call the function AddAUser() to the task scheduler,

I've tried this thing: Browsed it on the Task Scheduler

```
  C:\xampp\htdocs\post\application\controllers\cron_controller.php
```

Then at the Add arguments(optional): I put the AddAUser, so basically it became like this:

```
 C:\xampp\htdocs\post\application\controllers\cron_controller.php AddAUser
```

then I've tried running it, but I haven't seen anything in the database! What is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Model Like This code:

```
<?php 
class cronjob extends CI_Model{

public function __construct()
{
    //load and config db
    $this->load->database();
    parent::__construct();
}
public function adduser($firstname,$lastname){
$data = array(
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname
    );
$query = $this->db->insert('user_account',$data);
return $query;
   }

}
```

Change Controller to:

```
  <?php
    //Change It to `class Cron extends...` maybe your Prefixes have conflict
    class Cron_Controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();


    // this controller can only be called from the command line
    if (!$this->input->is_cli_request()) show_error('Direct access is not allowed');

}

public function AddAUser(){
    //Database Load is accable just in a Model Class
    $this->load->model('cronjob');
    $fname = "JUNCEL";
    $lname = "CARREON";

    $this->cronjob->adduser($fname,$lname);
}

}
```

Database loader is in a wrong place and prefixes may be have conflict.

Comment: Codeigniter is an old framework ! , Please use a new framework Like `Yii` , `Phalconphp` , `laravel`  , Or other micro frameworks for little projects

Comment: oh well! i will practice laravel after our thesis, but this thing isnt working what i am trying to ask is what will I put in the task scheduler! what urls

Comment: Please put your error code here for check it!  This code working good in all my projects, remove `if (!$this->input->is_cli_request())` and test it in browser